# Get Current Month and Year from Date Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Looking to get the current month and year from date column.

Below one not working:

```
FORMAT(Date(MONTH(Dim.DateTable.Date.Today())),"MMMM")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an extra column with only the month, you can use:

```
FORMAT(yourTable[yourDateColumn],"MMMM")
```

If you want a date to show consistant over your report as MMMM yyyy, select the column, click tab modeling and select the format of the column there.